# Swatch panel size in color picker flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Is there any way to change the size of the swatch panel in Flex's color picker control? This does not work:

```
colorPicker { swatchHeight: 21; swatchWidth: 24; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 'swatchPanelStyleName',like this:

In CSS,

> .swatchStyle { swatchHeight: 21;
>   swatchWidth: 24; }

In MXML,

```
<mx:ColorPicker swatchPanelStyleName="swatchStyle"/>
```